# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS under Parallels: Graphic Distortion after update

Tags: updates, xorg

```
Hardware:
 - Apple MacBook Pro RETINA 13", Late 2013

SOFTWARE:
 - OSX 10.9.5 (13F34)
 - Parallels Version 10.0.2 (27712)
 - Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
              ° Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
              ° Release:    14.04
              ° Codename:   trusty
```

When updating Ubuntu with Software Update, at some point some software is giving the unit video distortion.

It seems after a couple of rebuilds of Ubuntu and running Software Update, that the issue comes from:

```
Software Update:
Ubuntu base
Xorg X server - core server

Technical description:

Changes for xserver-xorg-core versions:
Installed version: 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2
Available version: 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.1

Version 2:1.15.1-0ubuntu2.1: 

  * Copy utopic package back to trusty.
    - Fix ppc64el byte order. (LP: #1333422)
      + xi-dont-copy-too-much.patch
    - Fix valgrind issue with xi copying too much.
      + xi-dont-copy-too-much.patch
    - Fix crash related to suspend/shutdown. (LP: #1208473)
      + mi-dont-process-disabled.patch
    - Fix touch event history overflow.
      + xi2-resize-touch.patch
    - Fix switching to guest sessions. (LP: #1322212)
      + Revive drm_device_keep_trying.patch
```

[image]

Please feel free to request additional info.

Comment: Thank you KasiyA for the edit. I was half asleep as I wrote this up.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me with PD 10.2.1 as well.

Fortunately the Parallels tools installer launched automatically and all I had to do is to type the admin password, hit Enter, wait a few minutes while it finishes installing and reboots the VM.

After that it was back to normal.

Comment: Couldn't thank you more by showing the tip. But it is really funny to ask Parallels to reinstall via "Actions|Reinstall Parallels Tools", and watch a black canvas while typing my password and Enter. Luckily the busy status of both hard disk and the ISO image indicate the progress, and now I have the machine back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well on basically identical hardware/software (2012 Macbook pro retina, Parallels 10, Ubuntu 14.04).

After snapshotting/retrying a couple of times, I put a hold on two packages, and it seems to work after running the rest of my upgrades:

echo "xserver-xorg-video-intel hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections

echo "xserver-common hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections